# Дата прописью на PHP

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.

В страничке есть 3 переменных: $dd, $mm, $YYYY, которые уже заранее равны дню, месяцу, году. Хотел сделать вывод даты прописью с значениями переменных. В инете ничего короткого не нашел, точнее там вообще ничего не нашел. В принципе можно написать ручками код, но если перечислять числа дня и года по порядку будет очень длинно.

Может у кого есть решение по отображению даты прописью? Прошу поделиться.

Comment: Как вариант может сойти: прописать все цифры со скланениями по отдельности и соответственно правилам выводить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У гугла все есть.
Вот пример на месяца

```
function russian_date(){
$date=explode(".", date("d.m.Y"));
switch ($date[1]){
case 1: $m='января'; break;
case 2: $m='февраля'; break;
case 3: $m='марта'; break;
case 4: $m='апреля'; break;
case 5: $m='мая'; break;
case 6: $m='июня'; break;
case 7: $m='июля'; break;
case 8: $m='августа'; break;
case 9: $m='сентября'; break;
case 10: $m='октября'; break;
case 11: $m='ноября'; break;
case 12: $m='декабря'; break;
}
echo $date[0].'&nbsp;'.$m.'&nbsp;'.$date[2];
}
russian_date();
```

---

ещё вариант

```
<?php
    // Установливаем русскую локаль
    // или setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU'); в PHP 4
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'rus_RUS');
    // Получаем сегодняшнюю дату
    // Формируем вывод
    // %a - короткая запись дня недели (Чт)
    // %A - обычная запись дня недели (Четверг)
    // %Y - год полностью (2008)
    // %y - год кратко (08)
    // Короче, смотрите маны
    $data = strftime("%a, %d/%m/%Y", time());
    // В PHP4 потребуется конвертация
    // $data = iconv('ISO-8859-5','windows-1251', $data);
    echo $data; // В PHP 4 название дня недели
    // будет начинаться с заглавной буквы
    // в обычной форме записи
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function date_rus($d, $m, $y) {
    $months = array('нулября', 'января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');
    return $d . ' ' . $months[$m] . ' ' . $y . ' года';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот статья по теме работа с датами в MySql. Там в конце как раз есть как получить дату пропись, причем без лишних заморочек.http://myshinobi.ru/rabota-s-datami-v-mysql/